# R: Search for rows with min value for 2-column index

Tags: r, data.table

My data table looks something like this:

```
team player score
A     1      1
A     1      3
A     2      2
A     2      5
B     1      2
B     1      3
```

I want to return the rows with the min score for each team/player combo.
e.g.,

```
A 1 1
A 2 2
B 1 2
```

I tried something like:

```
dt[, list(value=min(dt$score)), by=dt$team]
```

but that didn't work

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, , list(value = min(dt$score)),  : unused argument (by = dt$team)
```

and it wouldn't give me what I'm looking for anyway (only team mins).
Similarly, I tried:

```
dt[which(dt$score == min(dt$score)), ]
```

but that gave the min across the whole list (just A 1 1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: `dt[dt$score==ave(dt$score, dt$team, dt$player, FUN=min), ]` if `dt` is a data.frame (as mentioned in the error message).

Comment: You haven't converted your data set to a `data.table`. First do `setDT(dt)`. Also, you probably looking for something like `setDT(dt)[, .(value = score[which.min(score)]), by = .(team, player)]`

Comment: Lots of warnings and 0 row.
Warnings were:

    27: In FUN(X[[1100256L]], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: is setDT from a specific library?

Comment: From the `data.table` package... Aren't you using this package?

Comment: Here's a `dplyr` solution: `dt %>% group_by(team, player) %>% filter(score == min(score))`

Comment: My guess that `setDT(dt)[, .(value = min(score)), by = .(team, player)]` would be even better. Or `setDT(dt)[, .SD[score == min(score)], by = .(team, player)]` if you have many columns. Depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
aggregate(list(score = df$score),by = list(team = df$team,player = df$player),FUN = "min")
```

where df is your data frame.

Data frame:

```
> df
  team player score
1    a      1     1
2    a      1     3
3    a      2     2
4    a      2     5
5    b      1     2
6    b      1     3
```

Result:

```
> aggregate(list(score = df$score),by = list(team = df$team,player = df$player),FUN = "min")
  team player score
1    a      1     1
2    b      1     2
3    a      2     2
```

Comment: `aggregate(score ~ team + player, data=df, FUN=min)` is the same.

Comment: Perfect!
How do I bring over all the other columns from the df as well?

Comment: @mettle try `merge(...)`

Comment: might there be an easier way to bring them over in the 1st step, without having to do a subsequent merge? plus the merge re-adds all the non-min rows.